# Dojo and Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome, dojo

I am wondering, is there a possibility to use Dojo in order to create chrome extensions?

I've been searching for a quite a while, and it seems like there was some way before manifest_version 2. After that, I couldnt find anything more or less helpful.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: chrome extension are in javascript, so just create a normal extension and add dojo inside the project folder. then you can use it. here is nothing special to do. Just use it as you would use any javascript file

Comment: I tried, but from the first sight it looks like dojo is not supported in google chrome extensions. Maybe someone knows the way to use dojo in this case? some other indirect ways?

Answer (score 1):

There might be a fix of dojo CSP issue in Chrome extensions available in few weeks in Dojo version 1.11:
https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/15950

*'has("csp=restrictions")' was added for non-csp compliant code. Please set this feature test to true in order to run code that must be csp compliant.*

Answer (score 0):

I found this on google:
https://github.com/cesine/todomvc-for-chrome-extensions/issues/7

for records:

> It looks like dojo really does depends on eval (as of today Oct 26 2012)
>
> http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Chrome-extensions-manifest-version-2-problem-td3989459.html
>
> Line 15:
>   `var _41 = new Function("__text", "return eval(__text);");`
>
> The solution:
>
> Change the content security policy to use 'unsafe-eval' which after a great deal of lobbying by developers is now allowed as of September 7 2012

Comment: So, does it mean that its possible to use dojo in chrome extensions?

Comment: I tried to change policy in manifest file like that: 

"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",

 but it still doesnt work properly. However, everything works fine, when I am trying to run it as a standalone web-app